# Inserting date into mysql table using shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, datetime

I am totally new to shell scripting, and I am trying to insert the current date to a column in a database table using bash.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
CREATE TABLE DiskUsage (id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, DiskUsage VARCHAR(50), DateOfUsage DATETIME);
```

The table `DiskUsage` is successfully created in `shelltest` database.

Now, I am trying to insert values in this table using shell script:

```
dateOfUse=$(TZ=EEST date)
echo "Date: $dateOfUse"
$(df -h > t.txt)
while read Filesystem Size Used Avail Use Mounted on
do
    mysql shelltest -e "insert into DiskUsage (DiskUsage, DateOfUsage) values ('$Use', '$dateOfUse')"
done < t.txt
```

But when I try to execute this script, the date value for `DateOfUsage` is being inserted like this:

`0000-00-00 00:00:00` for all the records.

Can someone please tell me where I am mistaking? 
Thanks :)

Comment: What is the output of `echo "Date: $dateOfUse"` ??

Comment: The output is working fine: Date: Sun Mar 10 13:39:25 EEST 2013

Comment: why you not use NOW() in query instead of linux date format?

Comment: mmm actually as I mentioned before, i am new to shell scripting that's why i didn't think about using this function.

Comment: @Hanady: `NOW()` actually is a `current_timestamp`. If you want to use specific date then you follow answer, by @FreudChicken, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date does not spit out the format you need here per default, you need to give a format instruction

```
# date
Fri Apr 25 12:38:45 BST 2014

# date +'%F %T'
2014-04-25 12:38:45
```

so in your script it should be

```
dateOfUse=$(TZ=EEST date +'%F %T')
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql default format is 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss', so you need to insert in this mode.

Further why you are taking date from linux you can just place now() instead of $date. It will insert date automatically.

even you can leave it on mysql just set this data type as timestamp default current_timestamp and don't need to update this column as whenever row will be inserted mysql automatically insert current date time.